# Why do I get this error "Cannot cast from View to ClipData.Item"?

Tags: android

I have an item on ActionBar.
When the user click on it, dialog should pop up.

So I'm trying to select this parts by this code

```
mItem1 = (Item) findViewById(R.id.about)
```

However, I get this error so that I cannot define.

```
Cannot cast from View to ClipData.Item
```

Why is that? How can I fix?

**res/menu/main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="About this App"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the comment

> I have no idea what ClipData is about. All I want to do is selecting About this App on ActionBar as a trigger to show dialog. Then I'm facing this problem. Could you use my code and show me?

I try to answer the question as following:

Create a menu-layout-file **main.xml**:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/about"/>
</menu>
```

Create the activity **MainActivty**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.about:
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("About").setMessage("Text about about").setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // continue with delete
                }
            }).show();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: How should it look like?

Comment: It depends on where your class ClipData.Item is. What's the package declaration of this class?

Comment: I have no idea what ClipData is about. All I want to do is selecting `About this App` on ActionBar as a trigger to show dialog.  Then I'm facing this problem. Could you use my code and show me?

Comment: You gave me perfect answer! and it made me understood how the code has to be! Thanks so much! I appreciate it!

Comment: @micro.widmer I will create another question related to this. It'll be about the dialog that has 3 radio buttons in it. Please help!

Comment: @micro.widmer Here it is. Thanks:) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241447/how-can-i-show-the-dialog-that-has-three-radio-buttons

Answer (score 0):

ClipData.Item is not derived from the View class. findViewById has to return a View or a subclass of a View. Hence, the cannot cast error.